# Настроить форму обратной связи

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вот код модального окна. Как сделать, чтобы после заполнения данных (имя, мэйл, телефон) и нажатии отправить, появилось окно с этими введенными данными? (отправлять данные пока никуда не надо). Здесь же должна быть кнопка сбросить, которая возвращает пользователя на окно ввода данных. Как это все сделать?

```js
$(document).on('change', '.fofm input:checkbox', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(".fofm input[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.fofm input[type=hidden].valTrFal').val('valTrFal_true');
  } else {
    $(".fofm input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.fofm input[type=hidden].valTrFal').val('valTrFal_disabled');
  }
});

//закрытие модального окна
$('.close_modal, .overlay').click(function() {
  $('.popup, .popup2, .overlay').css({
    'opacity': '0',
    'visibility': 'hidden'
  });
  $('.popup > .fofm textarea').val('');
  //сброс всех полей формы обраной связи
  $(':input', '.fofm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
  $(".fofm input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

//показ модального окна
$('.open_modal').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.popup, .overlay').css({
    'opacity': '1',
    'visibility': 'visible'
  });
});

//аякс форма обратной связи

$(".fofm").submit(function() {
  var str = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact.php",
    data: str,
    success: function(msg) {
      if (msg == 'ok') {
        $('.popup2, .overlay').css('opacity', '1');
        $('.popup2, .overlay').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.popup').css({
          'opacity': '0',
          'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
      } else {
        $('.popup2 .window').html('<h5>Ошибка</h5><p>Сообщение не отправлено, убедитесь в правильности заполнение полей</p>');
        $('.popup2, .overlay').css('opacity', '1');
        $('.popup2, .overlay').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.popup').css({
          'opacity': '0',
          'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #84898b;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: #b1b7ba;
  font: 12px/18px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d6942d;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background: #ee7156;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 30px;
}

input[type="submit"]:disabled {
  opacity: .3;
}

body {
  font: 12px/18px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.open_modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.open_modal p {
  background: #ee7156;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 44px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
  display: block;
  width: 225px;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: default;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.popup,
.popup2 {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: justify;
  top: 40%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 999999;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
}

.popup form {
  padding: 0 27px 20px;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #72bffc;
  border-top: 40px solid #72bffc;
}

.popup2 .window {
  padding: 0 27px 27px;
  right: 0;
  width: 373px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #72bffc;
  border-top: 40px solid #72bffc;
}

.popup form input {
  background: #f0f5f7;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 227px;
}

.popup form input[name="txtname"] {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.popup form textarea {
  background: #f0f5f7;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 227px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: none;
}

.popup form label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px -2px;
  padding: 0;
}

.popup form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #ee7156;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 245px;
}

.popup form input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: auto;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.popup form h5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 29px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.popup .close_modal,
.popup2 .close_modal {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1px 9px 4px 9px;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'tahoma', sans-serif;
  background: #ee7156;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup2 h5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 120px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.popup2 p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup2 p strong {
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
}

.popup2 hr {
  background: #63baff;
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="open_modal">
    <p>Не нажимать</p>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="close_modal">x</div>
    <form class="fofm" action="">
      <h5>Форма обратной связи</h5>
      <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Имя" name="txtname">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="txtemail">
      <input type="tel" pattern="^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$" required="" placeholder="Телефон" name="txtphone">
      <label><input type="checkbox">Я не робот</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="valTrFal" class="valTrFal" value="valTrFal_disabled">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Отправить" disabled="disabled" name="btnsend">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="popup2">
    <div class="close_modal">x</div>
    <div class="window" name="Введенные данные">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Подозреваю что вам нужно еще одно модальное окно или вам придется скрывать эти данные на время "проверки", и собственно не совсем понятно что вы хотите от сообщества, готовый код? или просто чтоб вам сказали "длеать с помощью JS"? за вас работу делать никто скорее всего не возьмется, а вот подсказать в каком направлении искать проблему(если вы конечно выложите свой код) или подсказать советом(копать в том то направлени) - очень даже могут

Comment: Добавил код. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вывод данных в том же окне, думаю логика понятна, дальше добавляйте что хотите

update: код конечно править и править. Но вот уже работает, стили и порядок думаю наведете сами.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.fofm input:checkbox', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(".fofm input[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.fofm input[type=hidden].valTrFal').val('valTrFal_true');
  } else {
    $(".fofm input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.fofm input[type=hidden].valTrFal').val('valTrFal_disabled');
  }
});

//закрытие модального окна
$('.close_modal, .overlay').click(function() {
  $('.popup, .popup2, .overlay').css({
    'opacity': '0',
    'visibility': 'hidden'
  });
  $('.popup > .fofm textarea').val('');
  //сброс всех полей формы обраной связи
  $(':input', '.fofm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
  $(".fofm input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

//показ модального окна
$('.open_modal').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.popup, .overlay').css({
    'opacity': '1',
    'visibility': 'visible',
    'display': 'block'
  });
});

//аякс форма обратной связи

$('.btn__back').click(function() {
  $('.popup2').toggle();
  $('.popup').toggle();
});

$(".fofm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $('input[name="txtname"]').val();
  var email = $('input[name="txtemail"]').val();
  var phone = $('input[name="txtphone"]').val();
  var target = $('.popup2 .window');
  target.html('');
  target.append('Имя: ' + name + '<br>');
  target.append('Email: ' + email + '<br>');
  target.append('Телефо: ' + phone);
  $('.popup').toggle();
  $('.popup2').toggle();
});
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #84898b;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: #b1b7ba;
  font: 12px/18px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d6942d;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background: #ee7156;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 30px;
}

input[type="submit"]:disabled {
  opacity: .3;
}

body {
  font: 12px/18px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.open_modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.open_modal p {
  background: #ee7156;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 44px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
  display: block;
  width: 225px;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: default;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.popup,
.popup2 {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  //opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: justify;
  top: 50%;
  //visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999999;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
}

.popup form {
  padding: 0 27px 20px;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #72bffc;
  border-top: 40px solid #72bffc;
}

.popup2 {
  display: none
}

.popup2 .window {
  padding: 0 27px 27px;
  right: 0;
  width: 373px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #72bffc;
  border-top: 40px solid #72bffc;
}

.popup form input {
  background: #f0f5f7;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 227px;
}

.popup form input[name="txtname"] {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.popup form textarea {
  background: #f0f5f7;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 227px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: none;
}

.popup form label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px -2px;
  padding: 0;
}

.popup .button,
.popup2 .button{
  background: #ee7156;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 245px;
}

.popup form input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: auto;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.popup form h5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 29px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.popup .close_modal,
.popup2 .close_modal {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1px 9px 4px 9px;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'tahoma', sans-serif;
  background: #ee7156;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup2 h5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 120px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.popup2 p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup2 p strong {
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
}

.popup2 hr {
  background: #63baff;
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="open_modal">
    <p>Не нажимать</p>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="close_modal">x</div>
    <form class="fofm" action="">
      <h5>Форма обратной связи</h5>
      <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Имя" name="txtname">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="txtemail">
      <input type="tel" pattern="^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$" required="" placeholder="Телефон" name="txtphone">
      <label><input type="checkbox">Я не робот</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="valTrFal" class="valTrFal" value="valTrFal_disabled">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Отправить" disabled="disabled" name="btnsend">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="popup2">
    <div class="close_modal">x</div>
    <h5>Результаты</h5>
    <div class="window" name="Введенные данные"></div>
    <input class="button btn__back" value="Назад">
  </div>
```

Comment: Добрый день. Ничего не получается у меня вывести...

Comment: Ну так я показал, что данные сериализуются. А так вы должны или перехватывать в переменную, или обрабатывать.

Comment: Напишите, как обработать?

Comment: Так тут знать нужно что делать, я пальцем в небо должен попасть?  Тут же все зависит от задач.

Comment: 1. вводим данные в форму (имя, телефон, мэйл) нажимаем отправить. Отправляться ничего никуда не должно. Должно появиться окно с введенными только что данными. Оно и появляется сейчас. Только без этих данных. 2. Внизу на этом же окне должна быть кнопка СБРОС - она возвращает в исходную форму.

Comment: Добавил, но проще было бы переписать.